# display prime numbers with upper and lower limit using iterators (not generator)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I get the values but it also prints 'None' for non prime values

```py
class Prime:
    def __init__(self, n1, n2):
        self.n1 = n1
        self.n2 = n2

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        num = self.n1
        self.n1 += 1
        for x in range(2, num):
            if num % x == 0:
                break
        else:
            return num


z = Prime(30, 200)
for k in z:
    print(k)
```

results:
None
31
None
None
None
None
None
37
None
None
None
41
None
43

Answer (score 2):

If a `break` is encounted in a **for/else** loop in Python, the `else` block is never executed. Hence, `None` is returned by default. That is almost certainly the root cause of your error.

Your function should probably look like this:

```py
    def __next__(self):
        num = self.n1
        self.n1 += 1
        for x in range(2, num):
            if num % x == 0:
                break
        return num
```

(Although now that I look at it, that `for` loop should probably be a `while` loop, I am not sure your logic is correct here)

[for/else reference](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/for_-_else.html)